# Quadratic Variation for $X_t= \int \sigma_s dW_s$ where $\sigma_s \in S$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation

Let $\sigma_s \in S$. Setting $X_t=\int^t_0 \sigma_s dW_s$ and partitioning the interval $[0,t]$ i.e. $0=t^n_0<t^n_1... $ such that $d_n=\max_i |t^n_{i+1}-t^n_i| \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, prove that

$\sum_i |X_{t^n_{i+1}} - X_{t^n_{i}} |^2 \rightarrow \int^t_0 \sigma^2_s ds$ (a.s)

Heres what I've got so far, I was wondering if you guys agreed with it and could help me finish solving this:

- $|X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_{i}} |^2 = |\int^{t_{i+1}}_{t_{i}} \sigma_s dW_s|^2$
- $E|X_{t^n_{i+1}} - X_{t^n_{i}} |^2$ via Isometry is $ \int^{t^n_{i+1}}_{t^n_{i}} E\sigma_s^2 ds$

I'm not so sure how the second bullet point can help me though....

Comment: You're kindoff spamming the stochastic process and related tags. You really shouldn't ask this many questions all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

You need to compute the first and second moments.

Use your ito isometry expression to get an expression for the first moment of the sum.

Then you need to compute the second central moment. This will be an expression involving $|\Delta X|^4$. If you show that the second central moment vanishes in the limit, you'll be done.

Comment: You mean $E[\Delta X - E(\Delta X)]^2$? Which I assume is the Var $\Delta X$?

Comment: No, you'll need the fourth power. $E[\Delta X^4 - E[\Delta X^2]^2]$

Comment: Well, it's even a little more complicated than that actually because you need the variance of the whole sum so you'll also get cross terms. But you should be able to simplify those using independence.